# how to combine two dataframes in two different lists having same names into a single list with dataframes using R

Tags: r, dataframe, data-manipulation, data-management

I have a list with a set of dataframes called 'a' and the structure is as shown in the following picture

[image]

I have another list with a set of dataframes called 'b' and having the same names as in 'a' and the structure is as shown in the following picture

[image]

i would like to combine the two dataframes in two lists as per their names into one list with dataframes.

for this, I am using the following code

```
c <-  Map(cbind, a, b)
```

but, the code is not working as it is giving the following output

[image]

the expected output will look very similar to as shown in the following picture

[image]

for instance in a list of length 49, a dataframe with 241 rows and 14 columns

I don't know what is the issue with the code...... looking to solve this problem
I have tried all the options avalibale in stactoverflow to solve the problem

Comment: Can you create a small but reproducible example of the data that you have and show the expected output for it? Images are not the best way to share data. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem is with the structure of the two dataframes are different and the problem is solved by converting the structure of two lists into the same structure.

i have converted the structure of list 'b' into tibble as

```
b <- tibble::as_tibble(b)
```

then we can use the code as following

```
c <-  Map(cbind, a, b)
```

this has worked solved my problem